# Getting set up with intelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

Really basic question here but this has always stopped me from using any JetBrains product, but here I am trying once again. I also have the same issues with CLion but that will be for another time and hopefully I can figure it out based on some feedback from this post.

I need to set up my environment in IntelliJ. Nothing special. No build tools. Currently I just run my school projects using

```
javac Main.java
java Main
```

This has gotten me so far but I really want to use IntelliJ tools to their full capacity.
I want to be able to set break points and step in and out of my code in their debugger and all the other nice tools that come with running my code through IntelliJ

Every get started tutorial that I have watched on YouTube or from JetBrains themselves already has a basic build configuration set up to run your basic "Hello World" application and that is what I think I need. Just compile my java files into classes and run/debug them.

This is what the run configuration icon in the IDE should look like

[image]

And this is what mine currently looks like

[image]

I have set many different JDKs to go along with my projects but none of them seem to get the tools I need set up in the IDE. I have even let IntelliJ download one for me and set it up itself to see if maybe I downloaded and installed it wrong and IntelliJ maybe wasn't recognizing it.

This picture below is showing the project structure for an application that I let IntelliJ download a JDK for and set it up itself

[image]

So if someone could help me that would be fantastic. Links to videos, blogs are welcome even though I know that isn't the convention on this forum but I think that would be sufficient for my situation. Thanks in advance!

---Update---

I have found that if I create a project in IntelliJ that I get all the default configurations that I need. The problem is when I need to get a project from VCS that I am not getting any of the configurations that I need to run/debug my program in IntelliJ.

Comment: Did you check the official documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html? What were the specific problems you faced while following these guides? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution here would be to click the green play button next to your main method, on the left where line numbers are displayed.

Intellij will configure a default java run configuration for you. It will be displayed in the menu for later use, like in the screenshot you posted, after your first run.

You can also create one using the to menu: Run > Edit run configuration to add some more options like arguments, environment variables (that only apply for the run config), etc.

A good starting point would be the [Intellij help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration.html) on that topic. This help pages are always a good start and you find comprehensible instructions there on every topic.

Another good resource is the Intellij by JetBrains YouTube channel. This [video about debugging](https://youtu.be/lAWnIP1S6UA) shows both ways I described above. They have lots of quick tutorials about lot of features, like code generation or build tools. Check out the channel's playlists for specific topics.

Update

The problem with the already created project is that the default/ folder is not marked as source folder. You can do that by File > 'Project Structure...' and set the default/ folder as Sources:

[image: Setup Sources]

The cause for intellij not recognizing this is because you didn't use a folder structure like the one of maven.

For source code:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
```

and for tests:

```
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

If you set it up that way IntelliJ everything works as expected. I created a pull request to your repo. If you check out the branch, IntelliJ will setup everything correctly automatically.

Comment: This is helpful however I think there was something wrong with how I was setting up my projects because I was not getting the option for the green play button or any default configuration. I found that if I create a new project in IntelliJ that I get all these options but if I pull them from VCS then I don't get them. I am going to update my question to reflect this change.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an example project?

Comment: Yeah, Here is a link to a java project that I created not using IntelliJ but when I open it with IntelliJ I am not provided with any run configurations and I am not sure how to add them. https://github.com/reharri7/javaDS/

I can create .class files through javac on the CLI and I get the green arrow in the left margin like I should; however, IntelliJ can't run it. It displays a message saying "nothing here".

If I had created this project in IntelliJ in the first place then it would have added the Command Line App run configuration for me.

Comment: I updated my anser

Comment: You are awesome thank you